# Create a client server calculator program in C using UDP socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, udp, rpc

I would like to add the functionality of evaluating arithmetic expressions for my simple client server application but do not know how. A client should be asked to input an arithmetic expression and the server should return an evaluation of that expression. The expression should separated into operation(+,-,/,*) and two non negative integer arguments. Server: This must implement an “Arithmetic Service” consisting of a dispatcher and the four operations
add, subtract, multiply and divide which should have identical prototypes:
`Status op( int , int , int *); // the last argument is for the result`

CLIENT CODE

```
#include "connection.h"
int clientSocket, z;
SocketAddress serverAddr, clientAddr, rSA;
socklen_t addr_size;
char _message[SIZE], reply[SIZE];

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int aPort = IPPORT_RESERVED + getuid();
    int rPort = IPPORT_RESERVED + getuid() + 1;

    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("\nUsage: client server_name ??\n example client 127.0.0.1\n");
        printf("Use q to close the session.\n");
        exit(BAD);
    }

    z = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    makeReceiverSA(&rSA, rPort);
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (clientSocket < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket creation failed!");
        exit(BAD);
    }
    else
    {
        makeLocalSA(&clientAddr);
    }
    bind(z, (struct sockaddr *)&rSA, sizeof(SocketAddress));
    if (bind(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, sizeof(SocketAddress)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Socket binding failed!");
        close(clientSocket);
        exit(BAD);
    }
    printSA(clientAddr);
    makeDestSA(&serverAddr, argv[1], aPort);
    makeReceiverSA(&rSA, rPort);
    printSA(serverAddr);
    while (strlen(_message) != 1 && _message[0] != 'q')
    {
        printf("\nEnter message to send: ");
        fgets(_message, SIZE, stdin);
        Message m, r;
        memcpy(m.data, _message, strlen(_message));
        m.length = strlen(_message);
        r.length = SIZE;
        if (DoOperation(&m, &r, clientSocket, serverAddr) == OK)
        {
            memcpy(r.data, reply, strlen(reply));
            printf("\nResponse: %s\n", r.data);
        }
    }
}

Status DoOperation(Message *message, Message *reply, int s, SocketAddress serverSA)
{
    Status ret;
    if (message->length > SIZE)
    {
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: BAD Message Length\n", WRONGLENGTH);
        return WRONGLENGTH;
    }
    ret = UDPsend(s, message, serverSA);
    if (ret == BAD)
        return BAD;
    ret = UDPreceive(z, reply, &rSA);
    if (ret == BAD)
        return BAD;
    return OK;
}

Status UDPsend(int s, Message *m, SocketAddress dest)
{
    ssize_t n;
    n = sendto(s, m->data, m->length, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(SocketAddress));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: Unrecoverable error\n", BAD);
        return BAD;
    }
    if (n != m->length)
        return OK;
}

Status UDPreceive(int s, Message *m, SocketAddress *origin)
{
    ssize_t n;
    socklen_t a = sizeof(SocketAddress);
    n = recvfrom(s, reply, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&origin, &a);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: Unrecoverable error\n", BAD);
        return BAD;
    }

    if (strlen(reply) > SIZE)
    {
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: BAD Message Length\n", WRONGLENGTH);
        return WRONGLENGTH;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

HEADER FILE

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* standard C i/o facilities */
#include <unistd.h> /* Unix System Calls */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* system data type definitions */
// #include <sys/wait.h> /* System Socket wait definitions */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket specific definitions */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* INET constants and stuff */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* IP address conversion stuff */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* needed for atoi() */
#include <netdb.h>

struct hostent *gethostbyname() ;

#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE 1000
#endif

typedef enum {
    OK,             // operation successful
    BAD,            // unrecoverable error
    WRONGLENGTH     // BAD message length supplied
} Status;

typedef struct sockaddr_in SocketAddress;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int length;
  unsigned char data[SIZE];
} Message;

extern void printSA(SocketAddress sa) ;
extern void makeDestSA(SocketAddress * sa, char *hostname, int port) ;
extern void makeLocalSA(SocketAddress *sa) ;
extern void receiver(int port) ;
extern void sender(char *message1, char *machine, int port);


extern Status DoOperation(Message *message, Message *reply, int s, SocketAddress serverSA);
extern Status GetRequest(Message *callMessage, int s, SocketAddress *clientSA);
extern Status SendReply(Message *replyMessage, int s, SocketAddress clientSA);

/*
 * To return BAD if sendto/recvfrom return negatives
 */
extern Status UDPsend(int s, Message *m, SocketAddress dest);
extern Status UDPreceive(int s, Message *m, SocketAddress *origin);

/*print a socket address */
void printSA(SocketAddress sa)
{
  printf("sa = %d, %s, %d\n",
     sa.sin_family, inet_ntoa(sa.sin_addr), ntohs(sa.sin_port));
}

/* make a socket address for a destination whose machine and port
   are given as arguments */
void makeDestSA(SocketAddress * sa, char *hostname, int port)
{
  struct hostent *host;
  
  sa->sin_family = AF_INET;
  if((host = gethostbyname(hostname))== NULL) {
    printf("Unknown host name\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  sa->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *) (host->h_addr);
  sa->sin_port = htons(port);
}

/* make a socket address using any of the addressses of this computer
   for a local socket on any port */
void makeLocalSA(SocketAddress *sa)
{
  sa->sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa->sin_port = htons(0);
  sa->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
}

/* make a socket address using any of the addressses of this computer
   for a local socket on given port */
void makeReceiverSA(SocketAddress *sa, int port)
{
  sa->sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa->sin_port = htons(port);
  sa->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
}

/*receive two messages via s new socket,
  print out the messages received and close the socket
  bind to  any of the addresses of this computer
  using port given as argument */
void receiver(int port)
{
  char message1[SIZE], message2[SIZE];
  SocketAddress mySocketAddress, aSocketAddress;
  int s, n;
  socklen_t aLength;
  int i;
  
  if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))<0) {
    perror("socket failed");
    return;
  }
  makeReceiverSA(&mySocketAddress, port);
  if( bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&mySocketAddress, sizeof(SocketAddress))!= 0){
    perror("Bind failed\n");
    close(s);
    return;
  }
  printSA(mySocketAddress);
  aLength = sizeof(aSocketAddress);
  aSocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
  if((n = recvfrom(s, message1,  SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&aSocketAddress, &aLength))<0)
    perror("Receive 1") ;
  else{
    printSA(aSocketAddress);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("M:%d", message1[i]); 
    printf(" Received Message:(%s)length = %d \n",
       message1,n);
  }
  if((n = recvfrom(s, message2,  SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&aSocketAddress, &aLength))<0)
    perror("Receive 2");
  else {
    printf("Received Message:(%s)length = %d \n",
       message2,n);
  }
  close(s);
}

/*do send after receive ready, open socket
  bind socket to local internet port
  use any of the local computer's addresses
  send two messages with given lengths to machine and  port
  close socket
*/

void sender(char *message1,char *machine, int port)
{
  int s, n;
  char message[SIZE];
  SocketAddress mySocketAddress, yourSocketAddress;
  
  if(( s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))<0) {
    perror("socket failed");
    return;
  }
  /*
    if((x = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &arg, sizeof(arg))<0)
    perror("setsockopt SO_BROADCAST---");
    exit(-1);
  */
  makeLocalSA(&mySocketAddress);
  if( bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&mySocketAddress, sizeof(SocketAddress))!= 0){
    perror("Bind failed\n");
    close (s);
    return;
  }
  printSA(mySocketAddress);
  makeDestSA(&yourSocketAddress,machine, port);
  printSA(yourSocketAddress);
  strcpy(message,message1);
  if( (n = sendto(s, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&yourSocketAddress,
          sizeof(SocketAddress))) < 0)
    perror("Send failed\n");
  if(n != strlen(message)) printf("sent %d\n",n);
  close(s);
}

#include <sys/time.h>
/* use select to test whether there is any input on descriptor s*/
int anyThingThere(int s)
{
  unsigned long read_mask;
  struct timeval timeout;
  int n;
  
  timeout.tv_sec = 1; /*seconds wait*/
  timeout.tv_usec = 0; /* micro seconds*/
  read_mask = (1<<s);
  if((n = select(32, (fd_set *)&read_mask, 0, 0, &timeout))<0)
    perror("Select fail:\n");
  // else printf("n = %d\n", n);
  return n;
}
```

SERVER CODE

```
#include "connection.h"
int serverSocket;
SocketAddress serverAddr, clientAddr;
socklen_t addr_size, n;
int i;
char _message[SIZE];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int aPort = IPPORT_RESERVED + getuid();

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (serverSocket < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket creation failed!\n");
        exit(BAD);
    }
    else
    {
        makeReceiverSA(&serverAddr, aPort);
        
    }
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(SocketAddress)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Socket binding failed!\n");
        close(serverSocket);
        exit(BAD);
    }
    printSA(serverAddr);
    addr_size = sizeof(clientAddr);
    makeDestSA(&clientAddr, "127.0.0.1", aPort+1);
    // clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    while (strlen(_message) != 1 && _message[0] != 'q')
    {
        Message m, r;
        char* art = "Message received!";
        memcpy(r.data, art, strlen(art));
        r.length = strlen(art);

        if (anyThingThere(serverSocket) > 0)
            if (GetRequest(&m, serverSocket, &clientAddr) == OK)
            {
                memcpy(_message, m.data, m.length);
                printf("\nReceived Message: %s\n", m.data);
                Status ret = SendReply(&r, serverSocket, clientAddr);
            }
    }
}

Status SendReply(Message *replyMessage, int s, SocketAddress clientSA)
{
    printSA(clientSA);
    Status ret;
    ret = UDPsend(s, replyMessage, clientSA);
    return OK;
}

Status GetRequest(Message *callMessage, int s, SocketAddress *clientSA)
{
    Status ret = UDPreceive(s, callMessage, clientSA);

    if (ret == BAD)
        return BAD;
    if (strlen(_message) > SIZE)
    {
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: BAD Message Length\n", WRONGLENGTH);
        return WRONGLENGTH;
    }
    else
        return OK;
}

Status UDPsend(int s, Message *m, SocketAddress dest)
{
    ssize_t n;
    n = sendto(s, m->data, m->length, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(SocketAddress));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("Send Error:");
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: Unrecoverable error\n", BAD);
        return BAD;
    }
    if (n != m->length)
        return OK;
}

Status UDPreceive(int s, Message *m, SocketAddress *origin)
{
    ssize_t n;
    socklen_t a = sizeof(SocketAddress);
    n = recvfrom(s, _message, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&origin, &a);

    // printf("%ld\n", n);
    // printf("%s\n", _message);
    // memcpy(&m->data, _message, strlen(_message));
    // printf("%s\n", m->data);
    // m->length = strlen(_message);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: Unrecoverable error\n", BAD);
        return BAD;
    }
    
    if (strlen(_message) > SIZE)
    {
        printf("\nError: \n\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: BAD Message Length\n", WRONGLENGTH);
        return WRONGLENGTH;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: That's _a lot_ of code there. Can you narrow down the issue? Where, exactly, are you having a problem? (Please visit the [help] and read [ask].)

Comment: You have described the assignment but not your problem. Server and client not talking? They are talking but receiving unexpected data for the expression? The result? Server having trouble parsing the expression?

Comment: This is a simple client server program that allows a client to type a message and the same message is returned by the server. I want to add functionality where the client types an arithmetic expression that is then evaluated by the server and the result returned.

Comment: your `if (argc <= 1)` check is wrong, the name of the executable counts towards `argc`, so this will always but at least 1

Comment: So you have no issues sending the string to the server? The question is about parsing and executing the expression?

Comment: looks like the server sends back a "Message Received" message and then does nothing else. Have you made an attempt to parse the string from the client and perform the calculation or am I missing it?